# Determine if an Arbitrary Element is Using CSS3 Animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm working on a widget for a web application. When the user selects something in the widget, I use a CSS animation to hide it, then change something in the page based on the selection. I use the `animationend` event to wait before proceeding.

The widget can have multiple themes, meaning someone might choose not use a CSS animation. I would like to separate logic and presentation as much as possible, so I would prefer to avoid making other themes use JS.

How can I handle the fact that I don't know if an animation is present?

I was hoping to do something like the following, but I can't find anything like `isAnimating` in documentation.

```
elem.classList.add('hide');
if(elem.isAnimating()) {
    elem.addEventListener('animationend', callback);
} else {
    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `animationstart` event.

```
var anmtn = false;
, switcher = function(){anmtn = !anmtn})
elem.addEventListener('animationstart', switcher);
elem.addEventListener('animationend', switcher);

//Poll for animation.
var e = setInterval(function() {
  if( anmtn )
  //code
},62)
```

That should work. Untested!

For a more dapper polling use:

> - http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
> - https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery

#### MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart.

Comment: This might work for my scenario if I add a lot of code, but it doesn't handle the general case. Is there a way to know for sure if an element is currently using an animation?

Comment: Tried something! ( Hoping... )